# Incorrect class is getting referenced in the final war file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jar

My project has many jars. Two jars have a specific class with same name. Both the jar contains a class named Response. One of the Response class in jar A has a method abc(). I am creating the reference of this class in a Service class and calling this method abc(). When I generate the war file using maven and run the project in my local system Tomcat which is integrated with the Eclipse, the method is found and there is no exception. But when I deploy the same war file in external AWS Tomcat, I am getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError. This must be because in the war file, the reference must belong to the class in another jar which does not have the method abc(). I cannot remove these classes as both are used.
Help.

Comment: Is the package structure same for both the classes?

Comment: Yes. Package structure is same. Also, I checked in Order and Export but those 2 jars are not listed in order and exports.

Comment: The same class name with the same package is simply not possible. Or better the import depends on the class path order which is simply a very bad idea. You should change either the class name or better the package cause this sounds like a bad design choice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only A's class to be included inside your uber jar, I believe you can exclude the class from jar B to be wrapped up inside you uber jar by using something along the lines of the following directive inside yuor POM file :-

```
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
             <exclusions> 
               <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> 
                <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId> 
              </exclusion> 
            </exclusions> 
           </dependency>
```

The above directive will include all the dependency jars inside hadoop client  core jar except for the commons-math3, so if you want to use a newer version (or say different version) of apache commons-math3, you can add that explicitly as a dependency inside your POM without having to worry about if the commons-math3 from hadoop core library would be wrapped up inside your uber jar

Comment: But I want to include both the classes from different jars.

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, you want access to 2 classes with identical name and identical namespace?

Comment: Yes. Few sets of classes use the class in jar 1 and few classes use the class in jar 2

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. If 2 classes have identical name and identical namespace they can't both exist in a single jar. It's like having 2 files with same name and extension under same directory

Comment: They exist in different jars and these two jars exist in 1 war

Comment: When your application is deployed, the jars are eventually unpacked and all the classes are loaded into the classpath. So, If 2 classes have identical name and identical namespace they both can't exist for a single application.